# How to stream data in Vapor Swift?

Tags: swift, server-sent-events, openai-api, vapor

I'm building an Open AI chat stream backend using Vapor Swift. It connects to Open AI API using MacPaw's [OpenAI](https://github.com/MacPaw/OpenAI) wrapper. But I'm unsure how to stream the result to the client using SSE rather than as a single response.

My current code looks like this:

```
    func postChatStreamHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        let openAI = OpenAI(configuration: configuration)
        let promise = req.eventLoop.makePromise(of: Data.self)
        let query = ChatQuery(model: .gpt4, messages: messages)
        openAI.chatsStream(query: query) { partialResult in
            switch partialResult {
            case .success(let result):
                if let detla = result.choices.first?.delta,
                   let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(result) {
                    promise.succeed(data)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                ...
            }
        } completion: { error in
            ...
        }
        return promise.futureResult.map { data in
            let response = Response()
            response.body = .init(buffer: ByteBuffer(data: data))
            return response
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use AsyncStream? You don’t need the wrapper if you can you can easily make a stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct GenericAIController: RouteCollection {
    private let service = AIService()
    
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        let routes = routes.grouped("api", "ai")
        routes.get("completion", "stream", use: generatePoemStream(req:))
    }
    
    func generatePoemStream(req: Request) async throws -> AsyncThrowingStream<String, Error> {
        let query = ChatQuery(
            model: .gpt4_1106_preview,
            messages: [
                .init(role: .user, content: "Write a poem")
            ]
        )
        
        let originalStream = service.chatsStream(query: query)
        
        return AsyncThrowingStream<String, Error> { continuation in
            Task {
                for try await element in originalStream {
                    if let stringElement = element.choices.first?.delta.content {
                        continuation.yield(stringElement)
                    }
                }

                continuation.finish(throwing: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}

extension AsyncThrowingStream: AsyncResponseEncodable where Element: Encodable {
    public func encodeResponse(for request: Request) async throws -> Response {
        let response = Response(status: .ok)
        let body = Response.Body(stream: { writer in
            Task {
                do {
                    for try await element in self {
                        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(element)
                        _ = writer.write(.buffer(.init(data: data)))
                    }
                    
                    _ = writer.write(.end)
                } catch {
                    // Handle errors as needed
                }
            }
        })

        response.body = body
        return response
    }
}
```